# Control persp mesh tile border colors

Tags: r, graphics

I'm having some trouble creating a perspective plot that looks exactly how I want it to look.  In particular, I am trying to get the mesh not to be visible at all.  If you look at the image on the left you can see faint lines running between the tiles.  I want it looking like the right image with no lines visible:

[image]

I specifically want a solution with `graphics::persp` or other base R function.  I am not interested in 3rd party packages like `rgl`.

I obtained the right by using `polygon` and specifying a `border` color to match the `col` color.  If I leave `border=NA` with `polygon` I get the same result as with `persp`.  However, it seems `persp` just takes the first border value and re-uses it, unlike `polygon` which matches colors to the polygons.

This is the code used to generate the image:

```
nr <- nc <- 10
mx <- matrix(numeric(nr * nc), nr)
par(mai=numeric(4))
col <- gray((row(mx[-1,-1]) * col(mx[-1,-1])/((nr-1)*(nc-1))))

par(mfrow=c(1,3), mai=c(0, 0, .25, 0), pty='s')
persp(
  mx, phi=90, theta=0, border=NA, col=col, r=1e9, zlim=c(0,1),
  axes=FALSE, box=FALSE
)
title('Persp border=NA')
persp(
  mx, phi=90, theta=0, border=col, col=col, r=1e9, zlim=c(0,1),
  axes=FALSE, box=FALSE
)
title('Persp border=col')
plot.new()

mxpoly.x <- rbind(
  c(row(mx)[-nr, -nc]), c(row(mx)[-1, -nc]), c(row(mx)[-1, -1]),
  c(row(mx)[-nr, -1]), NA
)
mxpoly.y <- rbind(
  c(col(mx)[-nr, -nc]), c(col(mx)[-1, -nc]), c(col(mx)[-1, -1]),
  c(col(mx)[-nr, -1]), NA
)
title('Polygon')
polygon(
  ((mxpoly.x - 1) / (max(mxpoly.x,na.rm=TRUE) - 1)),
  ((mxpoly.y - 1) / (max(mxpoly.y,na.rm=TRUE) - 1)),
  col=col, border=col
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a result of antialiasing.  When each cell is drawn, the background is white, so antialiasing means the border pixels are drawn in a lighter colour.

On a Mac, you can fix this by turning antialiasing off.  Your first example gives

[image: screenshot with antialiasing]

by default, but if I open the graphics device using

```
quartz(antialias = FALSE)
```

and then run the identical code, I get

[image: screenshot with no antialiasing]

Turning off antialiasing can cause jagged edges, so this might not really be an acceptable solution to your real problem if it has diagonal lines.

You might be able to get things to work by drawing the surface twice with antialiasing:  the first time will show borders, the second time might still show something, but should show less.  However, `persp()` has no `add = TRUE` argument, so drawing things the second time is likely to be tricky.

If you're not on a Mac, you'll need to read about the device you're using to find if it allows control of antialiasing.

Edited to add:  I tried modifying the C source to the `persp` function 
to draw the surface 2 or 3 times.  The boundaries were still slightly 
visible when it was drawn twice, but invisible with 3 draws.

Comment: Nice, I'll try to figure out if there is a way to override the re-draw (e.g. running the internal functions directly to avoid the `plot.new` call).